# Redis connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, redis

Пробую запустить скрипт zbx_redis_stats.js в консоли получаю ответ

```
/etc/zabbix/script/redis/zbx_redis_stats.js 
Error: Error: Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
```

Редис запущен и работает. Порт слушает. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том что для работы скрипта нужен nmp не ниже 2й версии. После обновления всё заработало.